# How to embed i18n string into a react native elements button

Tags: react-native

I have the following working code for the title of a button in react-native (the button is a react-native-elements button).

```
<Button
          large
          title = {`Pay ${recipientForename}`}
```

This happily shows the relevant text, depending on who the recipent is , e.g. "Pay Tony", "Pay Sarah"  etc.

I am also using i18n-js, and have a multi-lingual phrase 'payments.Pay' (accessed from a json file) which I want to use instead of the word "Pay". The phrase can be successfully accessed when using the text tag, e.g.

```
<text>{i18n.t('payments.Pay')}</text>
```

but when I try and embed

```
{i18n.t('payments.Pay')}
```

into the above "title" line, nothing seems to work.

What syntax should I use to successfully embed the i18n phrase?

Comment: Why can't you just combine it with payments.Pay? Is I18n so necessary in this case?

Comment: Just to clarify, i18n is needed so that when the app runs in different locales, the relevant words for "Pay" (in different languages) , is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax in your localization file:

```
payments.Pay: 'Pay %{name}'
```

And then in the code:

```
<Button
    large
    title = {i18n.t('payments.Pay', {name: recipientForename})}
```

...